# why text-align property behave differently on different tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

could you please tell me why text-align property behave differently on different tag ?

I take two case In both case I want to centre my text . 
In first case I take a parent as **div** tag in side that I take anchor tag .If I need to centre align I apply property to parent

```
div {
    background-color:green;
        width:80px;
      text-align:center
}
```

But In second case when I take **ul** as parent inside that I take same anchor tag .to centre align the text I apply property to anchor tag why ?

```
ul a{
    color:red;
   text-align:center
}
```

Both fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ybnzajoo/

https://jsfiddle.net/pc939y7k/

how to know where I will write this property on parent or element 
I want when I need to write property on parent and when I will write same property on element.

When I will write **text-align:center** property to parent or when I will write **text-align:center** to same element

Comment: What exactly you want clarify your question.

Comment: I want when I need to write property on parent and when I will write same property on element

Comment: To have a proper answer to your question, may I ask you to reconsider to change your accepted answer. The now accepted one does not answer your question _why text-align property behave differently on different tag?_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't get the same output with same css because `ul` default assign margin and padding property if you dont assign. You can get the same output with below code.

```
<style>
    div {
        background-color:green;
        width:80px;
        margin: 16px 0;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    div a{
        color:red;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<div>   
    <a>hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you are giving  padding-left: 40px; that why it is comong in center ..if you remove  text-align:center; still it is center

Comment: my question is when I add text-align:center; property to parent and when I add text-align:center; to same element so that my element is centerally align

Comment: @user944513 thats because you are using `ul` and `ul` automatically add padding for list sign.

Comment: @user944513 add `ul { background-color: green; padding: 0; width: 80px; }` in place of `ul { background-color:green; width:80px; }`. then check. As i said if you dont give padding property to ul then it by default use padding.

Comment: it is not center align

Comment: You have to give `text-align: center;` to `ul` and then check.

Comment: @user944513 If this conversation is useful to you then upvote it... :)

Comment: @user944513 Is this answer is userful for you?

Answer (score 1):

> When I need to write property on parent and when I will write same
>   property on element?

You don't set the "text-align" property to the element which is to be centered, you set it to the parent of the element to be centered.

Src: [16.2 Alignment: the 'text-align' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align)